# Opentelemetry + Tracing + Metrics with APM, Prometheus and grafana

Tags: prometheus, grafana, open-telemetry

I'm studying about open telemetry but some concepts are still very confusing...
Does it make sense to collect tracking with automatic instrumentation, forward it to an apm like Zipkin or Elastcsearch APM, and have those values logged to a prometheus?

The idea would be to centralize all my information in grafana, where I already have several dashboards in a control room.

In short, I just needed the request values. Response time, latency...

Comment: Why do you need middleman in for of Elastic here? Expose metrics straight from your application.

Comment: You have concept of observability data types: metrics, logs, traces. Each type is specific and it has usually also specific storage. Also you can "calculate", e.g. response time can be stored directly as a metric, but it can be also calculated from stored logs or traces. I would stick with the type where you have good knowledge (probably metrics).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different questions:

> Does it make sense to collect (tracking) with automatic instrumentation?

Yes, it does.
I think by "tracing" you actually mean telemetry data, i.e. traces, metrics and logs.
Here's a good starting point: https://opentelemetry.io/docs/instrumentation/

> Does it make sense to forward the telemetry data to an APM?

Yes, there are several vendors that are able to process telemetry data from OpenTelemetry (using the OTLP protocol).
Some of those vendors have free tiers, in case you have a small application landscape or just want to try out a service.
The Grafana LGTM stack also offers an [open source solution for OpenTelemetry](https://grafana.com/docs/opentelemetry/).

> ... and have those values logged to a prometheus

Prometheus is a metrics database, which is used e.g. by the Grafana solution.
Other vendors use other metrics databases, which sometimes use their own query language rather than PromQL.

> The idea would be to centralize all my information in grafana.

Yes, I agree that this is a good idea, because grafana allows you to consume data from many different backends. Some vendors nudge you towards their own dashboarding tool, but all services give the access to the same telemetry data that your application generated.

Full disclosure: I work for Grafana Labs.